# HTTPS equivalent of Django's HttpResponse

Tags: django

For some reason I am in need of a `views.py` that returns only  some text. Normally, i'd use `HttpResponse("text")` for this. However, In this case I require the text to be send over `https`, to counter the inevitable mixed content warning.

What is the simplest way of sending pure text via django(1.7.11) over https?

Comment: Is a view required for this? I've done this kind of thing for things like google verification URLs directly like this:  url(r'google<tokenwhatever>\.html$', lambda r: HttpResponse("google-site-verification: google<tokenwhatever>.html", content_type="text/plain")). Not sure if this will work in your case.

Comment: This question appears to be based on a fundamental misunderstanding. HttpResponse doesn't specify that the response is sent over HTTP; the view - and in fact Django itself - has nothing to do with the method of communication with the client, that is entirely the responsibility of the server.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you, there was indeed a misunderstanding.  This means that the original question "simplest way of sending text over https" would simply be HttpResponse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django in the relevant docs of [`httprequest.build_absolute_uri`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) reads:

> Mixing HTTP and HTTPS on the same site is discouraged, therefore
>   build_absolute_uri() will always generate an absolute URI with the
>   same scheme the current request has. If you need to redirect users to
>   HTTPS, it’s best to let your Web server redirect all HTTP traffic to
>   HTTPS.

The docs make clear that

> the method of communication is entirely the responsibility of the server

as Daniel Roseman commented.

My prefered choice is to [force https](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/#https) throughout a site, however it is possible to do it only for a certain page.

The above can be achieved by either:

- Upgrading to a [secure and supported](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) release of Django where the use of [`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT) and [`SecurityMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.security) will redirect all traffic to `SSL`
- Asking your host provider an advice on how could this be implemented in their servers
- Using the [apache config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798882/2996101) files.
- Using `.htaccess` to redirect a [single page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16153030).

There are also other -off the road- hackish solutions like a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790430/how-do-i-require-https-for-this-django-view?noredirect=1&lq=1) which can be used with a decorator in `urls.py` to force `https`, or a [custom middleware](http://www.redrobotstudios.com/blog/2010/02/06/requiring-https-for-certain-paths-in-django/) that redirects certain urls to https.

Comment: I do need to force https. The decorator should work, but indeed seems a bit hacky.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen I have reformed my answer to make clear that there are plenty of legitimate solutions before you decide to chose a hackish one.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the mixed content problems as well. From my experience, you simply can't use the `HttpResponse` objects without running into trouble. I was never totally sure though and eventually found a way "around" it.

My solution for it was to use the `JsonResponse` object instead, to return JSON strings, kind of a work-around with the views returning something like:

```
mytext = 'stuff blablabla'
return JsonResponse({'response_text': mytext})
```

Which is super easy to parse, and OK with HTTPS.
Maybe not what you're looking for, but I hope it helps you find your way.